# How do you bind Params when you can't use variable name in bindparam?

Tags: pdo

I'm having trouble getting this PDO statement to work. I keep getting an Unexpected Variable warning on the first line with the first bindParam. I guess the problem might be that you can't use :Writing.ID is a bind param name? But that is the the variable name I need to call in the sql to get that variable, so how do I write the param to be error free and yet tell the code this param name is for that sql column?

```
$results = "SELECT
wp_users.ID,
wp_users.display_name,
stories.SID,
writing.ID,
writing.text,
writing.approved,
writing.position
FROM writing
LEFT JOIN stories on writing.SID = stories.SID
LEFT JOIN wp_users ON writing.ID = wp_users.ID
WHERE (stories.SID = :SID) AND (writing.approved = :approved) ORDER BY position ASC";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($results)
$stmt->bindParam(':wp_users.ID', $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':wp_users.display_name', $display_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':SID', $the_SID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':writing.ID', $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':writing.text', $text, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':approved', $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':writing.position', $position, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this a syntax error, the dot notation *$writing.ID* or *$writing.text* does not exists in PHP.
It sounds that you want something like $writing['text'] or $writing->text.

```
...
$stmt->bindParam(':writing.text', **$writing.text**, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

The marked syntax above is invalid PHP syntax!

### EDITED:

hmmm... it seems like that you haven't provided in your SQL string a wp_users.ID parameter of the :wp_users.ID of the form (prefixed by colon (:)).
OR
*You must bind only parameters explicitly set down in SQL*

Comment: But I changed it to just $ID in the first parameter (see code above) for the line I am getting the error on and I still get the error...

Comment: I cannot to understand why you give me an downvote. I sure that dot notation is a error.

Comment: I did not give you a downvote. Someone else must have. I do not see a downvote though. Anyway, there is no dot notation. My code just says $ID

Comment: @jaw  $writing.ID, $writing.text, $writing.ID, $writing.position are invalids var names, see the docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: See my updated code...there is no $name.name syntax anywhere and I still get the same error for the first parameter bind

Comment: This is the line getting the error: $stmt->bindParam(':wp_users.ID', $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);

Comment: Is it necessary to even bind params in PDO select statements? It does work for inserts and updates. Maybe it is not meant for select or maybe it is still secure at least without binding?

Comment: @felipsmarins  Correct--but how/where would I do that in a select statement?

Comment: In fact, I think you don't need bind $ID except if you use on SQL string. If so, maybe here: 
LEFT JOIN wp_users ON writing.ID = :wp_users.ID

Comment: Got it. So the only variables that I have to bind are those mentioned in the where clause? Maybe I'm not suppose to bind the rest of the columns mentioned in select statement?

Comment: Exactly. You must bind only parameters explicitly set down in SQL

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful news. However, the real issue I just figured out was that I forgot the ; after the prepare($results) statement!

Comment: Oh, its true! Also. I suppose that you not want pass variable by reference, so you should use bindValue rather than bindParam.